# How to apply filter on ng-options in case of nested json object

Tags: angularjs

I have two json arrays for country and for state. Now I have to filter the state drop down based on country selection.

```
    The two JSON arrays are like this.
    $scope.countries = [{id:1,json:{'key':'1',value:'INDIA'}},{id:2,json:{'key':'2',value:'USA'}}];
    $scope.states = [{id:1,json{'key':'1',value:'MAHARASTRA',prntkey:'1'}},{id:2,json{'key':'2',value:'TELANGANA',prntkey:'1'}},{id:3,json{'key':'3',value:'NEW YORK',prntkey:'2'}},{id:4,json{'key':'4',value:'TEXAS',prntkey:'2'}}].
    I am binding these json arrays to select tags of country and state using ng-options.

<select ng-model="country" ng-options="option as option.json.value for option in countries  track by option.json.key">
      <option value="">- Select -</option>
 </select>

<select ng-model="state" ng-options="option as option.json.value for option in states | filter:{prntkey:country.json.key} track by option.json.key">
       <option value="">- Select -</option>
 </select>
```

Now if I select the country as INDIA the corresponding states (MAHARASTRA, TELANGANA) should be populated in state drop down. The above code is not working. Can any one please rectify the mistake if any in the above code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is not valid JS code. And states don't have any prntkey property. Their json property have a prntkey property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second dropdown you are filtering with deep property 'prntkey'. To filter with deep/nested property, you need to provide complete path of property.
Use 
`filter:{json: {prntkey:country.json.key}}`
instead of
`filter:{prntkey:country.json.key}`

**Update:**
For keeping state dropdown empty if country is not selected, you can use custom filter function.

Add following function in your controller

```
$scope.filterState = function(input){
  return $scope.country && $scope.country.json.key === input.json.prntkey;
};
```

And replace state filter `filter:{prntkey:country.json.key}` with `filter: filterState`

Comment: Hi prasad, thx for your help. It is showing filterd states if I select country as INDIA but if I don't select any country it is showing all the states. My requirement is if I don't select any country the state drop down should be empty and if I select any one the corresponding states should populate.

Comment: Hi Prasad, can you please have a look at my above comment.

Comment: `$scope.filterState = function(input){
      return $scope.country && $scope.country.json.key === input.json.prntkey;
    };`    Use this filter function. And replace `filter:{json: {prntkey:country.json.key}}` with `filter: filterState`